# How to resolve the undefined reference error to readimagefile in dev C++

Tags: c++, error-handling, undefined-reference, dev-c++, bgi

I am getting an error in Dev C++ with the function readimagefile.
It says 'undefined reference to readimagefile' whenever I try to use the function included in the header file 'graphics.h'. Here is my code to show an image:

```
int main()
{
    initwindow(600,600,"Trial");
    readimagefile("alpha.jpg",0,0,500,500);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

It would be really helpful if someone could provide me with its correction or a substitute code to show an image.
Also if I input this image, would I be able to use this as a background? If not then what is the best way to import an image as a background in C++.

I have seen many people asking for help about this and fair enough, these errors doesn't show up on other compilers like code blocks or visual studio but I have to use Dev C++ so please make sure that your code is applicable in Dev C++.

Comment: Do you have `#include "graphics.h"` at the top of your cpp file?

Comment: Also try posting the full error.

Comment: The only thing I have left are the header file. Do not worry about that, I have included all the header files needed.

Answer (score 0):

> I try to use the function included in the header file 'graphics.h'

Assuming you posted whole file - you need to add `#include "graphics.h"` at the top of your cpp file if you want to use functions from it.

Also, it seems that you are trying to use WinBGIm - don't forget checking if you did every step from their [installation guide](https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/dev-c++/) - **especially** the part about needed linker commands:

```
-lbgi
-lgdi32
-lcomdlg32
-luuid
-loleaut32
-lole32
```

Comment: Well I haven't posted the whole program, I have included graphics.h and linked it properly. The initwindow() is working properly but not the readimagefile(). By the way, the only thing I have left is header-files.